# Change formula font size in LibreOffice

Tags: fonts, worksheet-function, libreoffice-math

I am trying to change the font size of the formula tool in LibreOffice. I have been told:

> To permanently change the default size (12 pt) used in LibreOffice
>   Math, you must first set the size (for example, 11 pt) and then click
>   the Default button.

The user interaction on this is incredibly frustrating - I cannot locate the "default button".

I would greatly appreciate some help. I am using LibreOffice 4.0.1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start LibreOffice Math and select "Font Size..." from the "Format" menu.  The default button is on the Font Sizes dialogue.

Comment: My my, I feel like a moron, thanks for your reply!